# Sort data ignoring case

Tags: java, criteria

I use blazebit in my project and I am faced with the task of making data sorting case insensitive. Solving a problem using blazebit does not seem like a primitive task. Tried to solve with Like but no luck. How can I sort by sortBy ignoring the case? Thanks in advance!

```
public <T> getResultForQuery(
    CriteriaBuilder<T> criteriaBuilder,
    String sortBy,
    boolean asc
) {

    CriteriaBuilder<T> tCriteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilder.orderBy(sortBy, asc).getResultList();
    ...
}
```

Comment: To sort the results in a case-insensitive way, you can use the lower function in your orderBy clause.
`CriteriaBuilder<T> tCriteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilder.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.lower(sortBy), asc).getResultList();` It will always make it in lowercase for comparision

Comment: com.blazebit.persistence.CriteriaBuilder has not lower function